# HtmlAgilityPack select "p" nodes that don't have child "p"

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

How can I efficiently select all nodes of type `x` that are not children of a node of type `x`?

Example with type as `p`:

```
<p id="top1">
    <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <p id="sub">
            <p id="sub_sub">
            </p>
        </p>
    </div>
</p>
<div>
    <div>
        <p id="top2">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The select should only return nodes with ids `top1` and `top2`

Comment: Shouldn't `sub_sub` be returned also?  Are you strictly looking for `p` nodes or _any_ nodes?  Your question isn't very clearly specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
elem.Descendants().Where(e => !e.Descendants("p").Any())
```